# External configuration file for section group

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

i have the following structure in my web.config:

```
    <sectionGroup name="MuniAxis">
        <sectionGroup name="BusinessEntitiesConstants" >
            <section name="FirmStatus" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null"/>
            <section name="OfferingStatus" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null"/>
            <section name="Role" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null"/>
            <section name="UserStatus" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null"/>
    <section name="BidStatus" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null"/>
    <section name="TransformTableTypes" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null"/>
        </sectionGroup>
  <sectionGroup name="Configurations" >
    <section name="LocalizationFormats" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null"/>
    <section name="SellSection" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null"/>
    <section name="SenchaFormatDate" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null"/>
    <section name="SenchaFormatDateHour" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null"/>
    <section name="SenchaFormatLongDateHour" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null"/>
    <section name="SenchaFormatShortLongDateHour" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null"/>
    <section name="ExportTemplates" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null"/>
  </sectionGroup>
</sectionGroup>
```

And then:

```
        <OfferingStatus>
    <add key="SC" value="dd52f926-b2a3-4d9a-af77-9654703f042b" />
    <add key="SM" value="a5702845-9846-4f3b-b05c-b2f767da1319" />
    <add key="PT" value="5bfb027e-4e84-4493-98fb-f63dbe11b6ab" />
    <add key="PN" value="ed2dc55e-81a0-4056-a20d-507a49d2b52f" />
    <add key="XM" value="3959478b-ce67-455e-a29c-f9e425c6040d" />
    <add key="NV" value="a496c982-0d0a-4ec8-a70d-6b41100da93c" />
    <add key="XS" value="bef615b7-eb26-4332-b350-106e6cbf4b6f" />
    <add key="CS" value="f675ffb5-c2f5-4df5-9115-8590e029b156" />
    <add key="FM" value="d371f202-2afd-46f9-b0c3-7999d6813939" />
    <add key="TS" value="2aff5a4f-9ff0-4dbc-8fe0-11bc0dcc2935" />
    <add key="AU" value="0042f7ee-c0ac-48f6-9c69-7e9ff2fa1129" />
    <add key="VB" value="9da3cc81-fba2-48fd-acec-56e6a7ec7d79" />
    <add key="CT" value="e66d03f4-f0b8-4247-ae5e-5f1f234bd8fe" />
    <add key="TB" value="69B711C5-D98C-439D-A196-DC841F6DD9FA" />
    <add key="TT" value="31598ec5-51e3-4536-a4f1-318dc44744b2" />
    <add key="CV" value="f6fc0dc8-c30d-4f6d-bbcf-5b18ab7f82c9" />
    <add key="NV" value="e4916043-43a4-4737-bd47-79cb68100697" />
    <add key="NS" value="8be0faa3-1ffa-4ab1-a144-8a7acece9f85" />
        </OfferingStatus>

  <BidStatus>
    <add key="C" value="7b49c6ff-af46-4cb6-a105-27fbb64c6844" />
    <add key="H" value="bac0d838-6497-427d-a261-24bb3e4b85b7" />
    <add key="F" value="b286a107-9bf8-47d5-8069-2af35ca2cebe" />
    <add key="O" value="a99fbcc6-97f8-440b-8d91-87be085756c1" />
  </BidStatus>

        <Role>
            <add key="Administrator" value="1CF63AFA-EDAD-4C8B-A02C-BB3B0C78C210" />
            <add key="ReadOnlyAdmin" value="A1610716-6FF0-45AF-83F0-72C53730295D" />
            <add key="HeadTrader" value="75BEAF5B-0403-4D64-97CC-04569C8BCA6A" />
            <add key="Trader" value="7EE59880-A80F-4710-BBA8-822029D3CB72" />
        </Role>

        <UserStatus>
            <add key="Active" value="22479ED8-6494-409A-9820-23D0AC662368" />
            <add key="Inactive" value="B7A69F67-5965-4DFF-8EA7-15545E2778DC" />
            <add key="PendingAgreement" value="A8AA5639-8700-4A7C-9564-EC8AC364A32A" />
        </UserStatus>

        <TransformTableTypes>
            <add key="ImportSellOfferings" value="C5B0513D-45EF-4F5F-9DF7-33044AACE475"/>               
        </TransformTableTypes>

 </BusinessEntitiesConstants>
<Configurations>
  <LocalizationFormats>
            <add key="DefaultCultureInfo" value ="en-US" />
    <add key="ShortDatePattern" value="MM/dd/yy"/>
    <add key="ShortTimePattern" value="hh:mm tt"/>
    <add key="ShortDateTimePattern" value="MM/dd/yy hh:mm tt"/>
    <add key="SenchaFormatDate" value="m/d/y"/>
    <add key="SenchaFormatDateHour" value="m/d/y g:i a"/>
    <add key="SenchaFormatLongDateHour" value="m/d/y g:i:s A"/>
    <add key="SenchaFormatShortLongDateHour" value="m/d/y g:i"/>
  </LocalizationFormats>
  <!--Configuration for Sell Section.-->
  <SellSection>
    <!--Configuration for Sell Section.
      DeadLineDateAuction: Limit Hour for Create a Auction and schedules for to today (format:HH:MM AM/PM).
      OffSetStartAuction: Default delay for initialize the Auction. The value indicate next half hour/next Hour etc... (format:HH:MM).
      InitialDateAuction: Default hour that will be initialize the Auction for next day (format:HH:MM AM/PM).
      OffSetEndAuction: Default duration default  of Auction (format:HH:MM).
      OffSetFirmUtil: Default delay for trade bond. (format:HH:MM).
      OffSetSettelmentDate:Default delay in days for Settlement. (format:dd).
      DeadLineOperations: Hour with System not permit more operations (format:hh:mm AM/PM).
      PermitEndAuctionUpTo: Hour up to End Auction (format: hh:mm AM/PM).
    -->
    <add key="DeadLineDateAuction" value="03:00 PM"/>
    <add key="OffSetStartAuction" value="00:30 AM"/>
    <add key="InitialDateAuction" value="09:00 AM"/>
    <add key="OffSetEndAuction" value="04:00 AM"/>
    <add key="OffSetFirmUtil" value="01:00 AM"/>
    <add key="OffSetSettelmentDate" value="03"/>
    <add key="DeadLineOperations" value="05:00 PM" />
    <add key="PermitEndAuctionUpTo" value="04:30 PM" />
  </SellSection>
  <ExportTemplates>
    <add key="BidDetailsExcelTemplate" value="D:\dev\MuniAxis\Code\trunk\MuniAxis\ReportTemplates\BidDetails.xlsx" />
    <add key="TraderReportExcelTemplate" value="D:\dev\MuniAxis\Code\trunk\MuniAxis\ReportTemplates\TraderReport.xlsx" />
    <add key="BidDetailsPDFTemplate" value="D:\dev\MuniAxis\Code\trunk\MuniAxis\ReportTemplates\BidDetails.pdf" />
    <add key="TraderReportPDFTemplate" value="D:\dev\MuniAxis\Code\trunk\MuniAxis\ReportTemplates\TraderReport.pdf" />
  </ExportTemplates>
</Configurations>
</MuniAxis>
```

I'd like to move everything inside MuniAxis to an external file. I know this isn't possible using configSource because it's not available for section groups, is there any other way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

use [ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openmappedexeconfiguration.aspx) to open the configuration file where you have placed desired section group/section definitions and related data.

The link has an example to to give you kick start.

Comment: But how do i defined this in my web.config? Or i don't define the sections at all?